# angularjs: orderBy sort not working correctly for multiple field types

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have a table that contains multiple field types (string, dates, addresses).  The orderBy seems to be working for Dates and Case Number, which contains both letters and numbers, however it doesn't seem to be working correctly for addresses and strings.

```
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>
         <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll()"/>
      </th>
      <th>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="sortType = 'case_num'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
         <span ng-show="sortType == 'case_num' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
         <span ng-show="sortType == 'case_num' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span>
         ${Case Number}
         </a>
      </th>
      <th>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="sortType = 'short_desc'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
         <span ng-show="sortType == 'short_desc' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
         <span ng-show="sortType == 'short_desc' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span>
         ${Short Description}
         </a>
      </th>
      <th>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="sortType = 'start_date'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
         <span ng-show="sortType == 'start_date' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
         <span ng-show="sortType == 'start_date' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span>
         ${Start Date}
         </a>
      </th>
      <th>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="sortType = 'work_location'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
         <span ng-show="sortType == 'work_location' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
         <span ng-show="sortType == 'work_location' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span>
         ${Work Location} 
         </a>
      </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in c.onbCase | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchTable track by $index" ng-if="item.case_visible">
      td><input type="checkbox" id={{item.number}} ng-click="checkboxFunc(item)" ng-model="item.checked" ng-checked="selectAll || item.checked"/></td>
      <td>{{item.number}}</td>
      <td>{{item.short_description}}</td>
      <td>{{item.start_date}}</td>
      <td>{{item.location}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

When I sort by Case Number and Start Date, the entries order correctly.  However, when I try to sort by Short Description or Location, it doesn't seem to ordering it correctly:

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something?  THanks!

Comment: The property is named `location`, but you sort by `work_location`. Same mistake for the description (`short_desc` vs. `short_description`).

Comment: oh man...so simple, i must have overlooked this!